# Reading the javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to write a script for an auto bet (bustabit.com)

they have a manual about this on [github](https://github.com/bustabit/autobet)

I want to read the "bust" object in the engine.history for writing an if statement

but I have no idea how javascript objects work ( i have not any experience in programming much )

I tried this but it's not working

```
if (engine.history(game.bust)=1.37){log("bust is 1.37")};
```

can someone help?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: the `=` sign should be an `==` sign. Yup I know how that feels when u miss on that especially when a program is large.. `if (engine.history(game.bust)==1.37){log("bust is 1.37")};`

Comment: Or try `engine.history.toArray().filter(game => game.bust === 1.37)`. Just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equal character is for assignment.

You should use **==** for equality checks [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

```
if (engine.history(game.bust)==1.37){log("bust is 1.37")};
```

Then

history(game.bust) means that history is a function which is taking a param which is is the value of the property bust inside the game object

[Reading what are you sharing](https://github.com/bustabit/autobet#interacting-with-the-game) history has a method in it, which is going to cast the history to an array.

```
engine.history.toArray()
```

After that you can use array methods in order to find the history item you are looking for, for instance

```
const engineHistory = engine.history.toArray()
const element = engineHistory.find(historyItem => historyItem.bust == 1.37)
```

Comment: if i want to add an if statement to this:   

const engineHistory = engine.history.toArray();
if(const element = engineHistory.find(historyItem => historyItem.bust == 1.14))
{
notify(its working);
};

like this ?

Comment: @anoobprogrammer it won't work like that, you can do something like this: 
`if(element) console.log('its working')` 
Because of the truthiness of the result of the array's found element, [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=it)